# Weird UITableViewCell bug: accessory views change at random?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So, I have a UITableView set up to display all the system languages, where the user can select one. Upon selection, the cell sets its accessory view to a check mark and sets all the other cells' accessory views to none. But for some reason, when one cell is selected, another cell will randomly get selected as well.

For example: Here I select English UK.

[image]

But then when I scroll down (here showing the bottom of the list), English US seems to have automatically selected itself.

[image]

And then when I scroll back up to the top, English UK has magically deselected itself, but Spanish has been checked somehow.

[image]

Here is the entire source of the ViewController subclass: http://pastebin.com/EYNS9ahk

I also tried implementing a delegate method to check if the tableview is inadvertently selected at any point, but that's not the problem. Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seem me fine and well written, I guess the issue could be with the cell reusability,

Try with do the below changes,

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d",index.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

let me know if you are still getting the same issue.

Comment: That fixes the second issue where a cell would automatically deselect itself, but it still somehow allows two cells to be selected at once. From what I can tell, a cell will mistakenly stay selected only if it is offscreen. EDIT: Nevermind, calling reloadData before adjusting the accessory views fixed that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the cell is reusable, when scrolling, the cells outside the view port will enqueue, and the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will dequeue the enqueued cells for reusing, the cells' property remain the status on enqueuing, so you need to set to new status.

to fix your problem, you need to remember the selected cell's indexPath or other things can identity the cell, and set the accessoryType for it in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do not rely on the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.